# Difficulty to open component from another module

Tags: angular

My example is: State and City.

I want to create a dropdownlist on view city with a fixed item like: "Add new item". When click on this item, a model will appears the state component to add new state.

I already imported StateModule inside the CityModule, but when I click to open any view of city it open state instead of city... (image below)

city.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ StateModule, ...],
  declarations: [ ... ]
  ...
})
```

Cidade = City | Estado = State | Cadastro = Register

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT**

I didnt do the dropdownlist yet

```html
<button (click)="modal()">Click Here</button>
```

```
modal() {
   this.ngbModalService.open(AddStateComponent,{size: 'lg'});
}
```

Routes

```
export const CityRouterConfig: Routes = 
[
    {
        path: '', component: CityComponent,
        data: {
            title: 'City',
            urls: [{ title: 'Cities', url: '/cidade' }, { title: 'City' }]
        },
        children: [
            ...,
            { path: 'add', component: AddCityComponent,
                data: {
                    title: 'City',
                    urls: [{ title: 'Cities', url: '/cidade' }, { title: 'City' }]
                }
            }      
        ]
    }
]
```

**About duplicated**

My `open` is with a `component`.

The link is with a `"string" html`.

I don't understand the link and what I have to do to solve my problem...

Comment: Please paste the parts of the code from which you call the State component, if possible the relevant parts of the templates as well. the more details you provide, the easier it will get to help you out. :)

Comment: It's look like your router.module is bad defined, but it's difficult know it

Comment: @LeoHenrique do you want to open one component in other component?

Comment: @AkaiCrystal Yes, I want to add a new State when I add a new City  (when necessary)

Comment: @BrunoFarias I updated the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for calling the NgbModal open method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464345/best-practice-for-calling-the-ngbmodal-open-method)

Answer (score 0):

**I solved with a shared module**

city.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule, ...],
  declarations: [ ... ]
  ...
})
```

state.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule, ...],
  declarations: [ ... ]
  ...
})
```

shared.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    declarations: [
        AddStateComponent
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [
    ],
    exports: [
        AddStateComponent
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```